# Obter prazo com Web Service dos Correios

Tags: php, libcurl, web-service

Estou tentando obter o prazo de entrega de forma dinâmica utilizando o WebService dos Correios, para isso estou utilizando essa [documentação](https://www.correios.com.br/a-a-z/pdf/calculador-remoto-de-precos-e-prazos/manual-de-implementacao-do-calculo-remoto-de-precos-e-prazos).

Se você entrar na [página de testes deles](http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx?op=CalcPrazo), é possível digitar o serviço de PAC, por exemplo, `4510` e os ceps origem e destino para obter o retorno em uma página XML.

Verifiquei que esse formulário faz um POST simples ao copiá-lo para meu localhost. Mas ao tentar fazê-lo sem o formulário, mas sim usando `curl` não tive sucesso.

Meu código até o momento é:

```
$data['nCdServico'] = '4510';
$data['sCepOrigem'] = '36572008';
$data['sCepDestino'] = '36700000';

$url = 'http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx/CalcPrazo';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($resp);exit;
```

Mas o retorno é `false`

Gostaria de uma ajuda pra saber o que estou esquecendo para que o retorno seja os dados do prazo de envio e não apenas o booleano false.

Comment: Por que não está usando [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)?

Comment: Apenas falta de conhecimento de como usá-lo.

Comment: Esse é um bom argumento, vou escrever uma resposta

Comment: Opa, estava almoçando, vou verificar ali. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O PHP possui a biblioteca nativa [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) que abstrai muitos aspectos do consumo de um webservice.

Para se conectar com o WS, é simples:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx?WSDL');
```

Você deve passar como parâmetro o endereço do WSDL, que é a descrição de como consumir o web service.

Você também pode passar alguns parâmetros, conforme abaixo:

```
$client = new SoapClient(
    'http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx?WSDL',
    array( 
        // Stuff for development. 
        'trace' => 1, 
        'exceptions' => true, 
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    ) 
);
```

- `trace`: habilitar as funções de debug (todas iniciam com "__").
- `Exceptions`: ativará que os erros serão lançados via exceptions (SoapFault)
- `cache_wsdl`: com o parâmetro `WSDL_CACHE_NONE`, não haverá cache.

Todos os parâmetros são focados para o desenvolvimento.

Após, o uso é tão simples quanto:

```
$data['nCdServico'] = '4510';
$data['sCepOrigem'] = '36572008';
$data['sCepDestino'] = '36700000';

$response = $client->CalcPrazo($data);
```

O resultado da consulta é:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["CalcPrazoResult"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["Servicos"]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
      ["cServico"]=>
      object(stdClass)#5 (8) {
        ["Codigo"]=>
        int(4510)
        ["PrazoEntrega"]=>
        string(1) "5"
        ["EntregaDomiciliar"]=>
        string(1) "S"
        ["EntregaSabado"]=>
        string(1) "N"
        ["Erro"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["MsgErro"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["obsFim"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["DataMaxEntrega"]=>
        string(10) "20/08/2018"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sendo uma `stdClass`, as propriedades devem ser acessadas como um objeto (pois, é um objet):

```
echo "Data máxima de entrega: ".$response->CalcPrazoResult->Servicos->cServico->DataMaxEntrega;
```

Saída:

> Data máxima de entrega: 20/08/2018

Comment: Vou tentar usar com SOAP e já te dou resposta, a primeiro momento deu um fatal erro de que a classe SoapCliente não existe no meu localhost. Vou ver pra instalar ela.

Comment: @DavidAlves windows ou linux?

Comment: Linux, mas estou conseguindo utilizar no meu servidor remoto.

Comment: Muito bom o resultado, vou passar a utilizar mais SoapClient com certeza! Muito obrigado